# Software for solving first-order logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, first-order-logic, math-software

Is there any class of software that can help me with the following problem in first order logic: given $\phi$ a formula with a "hole" in it (a subformula which is undetermined) and a particular set of assumptions $\Gamma$, find a formula $\psi$ such that $\phi$ with the hole replaced with $\psi$ can be proved under assumptions in $\Gamma$?

I don't expect to find a solution that works for any formula... I just wonder if there is a class of programs that try to solve this problem.

Comment: What if it is impossible? "$\bot \land {?}$" is never going to have any formula that can be substituted for "$?$" that would make it provable in any consistent theory.